# Pass method to function using method name from string variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, oop

I have a class with a constructor, two other methods, and a member list with the names of the two methods.

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.methods = ["self.foo", "self.bar"]
    def foo(self):
        print("foo")
        return 0
    def bar(self):
        print("bar")
        return 0
```

I have a function that takes a function as an argument, like this.

```
myFunction(func)
```

The function has global scope and would be used like this.

```
myFunction(self.foo)
```

I want to iterate through the items in the self.methods list and make a call to the function for each method name, but, as expected, a string is passed rather than the method itself. How do I pass the method like the above example, so like `self.foo` not `"self.foo"`?

Comment: Where is your `myFunction` scoped? Is it part of `Foo` or is it stand alone? If it's going to try and call a function by name is there any reason it doesn't accept an argument of an instance of something to use or...?

Comment: @JonClements myFunction has global scope. What do you mean by an instance of something to use?

Comment: How does `myFunction` know what object it's supposed to look at methods for and loop and run those methods?

Comment: I'm still struggling with what you're really trying to achieve here... but I'm going to take a guess that let's say you have a `foo = Foo()` (with `self.methods = ['foo', 'bar']`), then you can do `for f in foo.methods: getattr(foo, f)()`...

Comment: @JonClements `getattr()` was what I was looking for, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you can try this.

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.method=['foo','bar']
    def foo(self):
        print('foo')
    def bar(self):
        print('bar')
    def run_all(self):
        for m in self.method:
            getattr(self,m)()
```

---

```
a=Foo()
a.run_all() # iterating through self.method and executing them
# foo
# bar
```

Comment: This is kind of what I'm looking for, but `self.method` can't be a dictionary, it can only be a list containing only the strings.

Comment: `run_method` is a bit of an odd name there considering it doesn't actually run anything - it just does an attribute lookup... I'd either rename that or actually make it call the method, and then since you've got the logic inside that function to do so, actually call it within `run_all` instead of repeating yourself with the `getattr` stuff

Comment: @JonClements Agreed. Editing the answer. Thanks for the suggestion. ;)

Comment: This looks like exactly what I'm looking for, but for some reason I get `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` when executing `a.run_method('foo')()`.

Answer (score 0):

You want somwthing like this?

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.methods = [self.foo(), self.bar()]
    def foo(self):
        print("foo")
        return 0
    def bar(self):
        print("bar")
        return 0


foo_obj = Foo()
```

Comment: This is going to to call the functions in the `__init__` and then stores their results in `self.methods`- so as soon as you create a `Foo` instance, you'll get foo / bar printed, then `self.methods = [0, 0]`... that's likely not what the OP intends

Comment: The `self.methods` has to be strings, that's what I'm having trouble with understanding how to do

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.methods = self.foo, self.bar

    def run_methods(self):
        for method in self.methods:
            print('Running method {}'.format(method.__name__))
            method()

    def foo(self):
        print("foo")
        return 0

    def bar(self):
        print("bar")
        return 0
```

So, you can run your methods by calling `run_methods`. If you want to access their names as well, you can always do that via their respective `__name__` methods, as above.

```
f = Foo()
f.run_methods() 

# Output:
#
# Running method foo
# foo
# Running method bar
# bar
```

EDIT: As another person suggested, you should edit your question to describe in more detail what myFunction(fun) does. But inded, you should probably use a different approach than passing the actual names as strings.

Comment: OP mentioned *a string is passed rather than the method itself.*

Comment: Indeed.. Now I re-read and cannot understand what exactly they want to do with myFunction though

Comment: Yes, I too don't understand what OP is trying to do.

Comment: Seems the OP has said on another answer *The self.methods has to be strings, that's what I'm having trouble with understanding how to do*... so this answer is likely to be close... just leave `self.methods = ['foo', 'bar']` and then amend your `run_methods` to use `getattr(self, method)()` instead of `method()` (and your print will be `print('running', method)` or similar